# How to calculate this integral: $\int_{C}{} (z^2-2z) dz$ where $C$ is a line segment starting at $1$ and ending in $i$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, circles, contour-integration

The task is as follows:
$$
\text{Calculate } \int_{C}{}f(z) dz \text{, where }
\\
\text{a) } f(z)=z^2-2z \text{, } C \text{ - line segment starting at } 1 \text{ and ending at } i \text{;}
\\
\text{b) }f(z)=\frac{\bar{z}}{z+i} \text{, } C \text{ - circle } |z+i| = 3 \text{.}
$$

I do not know how to calculate either of the integrals. Any help or push in the right direction would be much appreciated. Thank you.

---

Update:

I calculated the $a)$ integral to be equal to $\frac{7}{3}-\frac{i}{3}$. If someone could check if I did good, that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint.

For (a), you can simply use the fundamental theorem of calculus (also true in complex analysis) since you have an entire function:
$$
\int_Cf(z)dz=F(B)-F(A)
$$
where $A$ is the initial point of $C$ and $B$ the final point, and $F$ is an antiderivative of $f$.

For (b), the first thing you need is to *parameterize* your path $C$, which means writing
$$
z=g(t),\quad t\in[0,1]
$$
for some function $g$.

Then
$$
\int_Cf(z)dz=\int_0^1 f(g(t))g'(t)dt.
$$

Comment: Okay, so is my $g(t)=i-\text{t}i+\text{t}$?

Comment: @bosendorfer: you have different $g$ for (a) and (b).// If the parameterization interval is $[0,1]$, you should have $g(0)=1$ and $g(1)=i$ for (a). // Can you work that out?

Comment: Well then in $a)$ it is $g(t)=1+\text{t}i-\text{t}$, right?

Comment: @bosendorfer: that's right. But there is a shortcut for (a), I have edited my answer. You only need to parameterize the path for (b).

Comment: @bosendorfer: do you know how to go on?

Comment: Not really, I am not sure how to parametrize the circle. Could it be $z(t)=-i+3\cdot e^{2 \pi \cdot i \cdot t}$?

Comment: @bosendorfer: yes, that's correct. Then you can go on.